# how to make the label skip the line

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code. How to a make, everytime I press the button, the label skip the line and don't eraser what was written before, just skip a line.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

roots = Tk()
roots.title("Email's save")
roots.geometry("500x500")
roots.resizable(False, False)

"""
e = email
p = password
"""

e = Entry(roots)
e.grid(row=0, column=1)
e.focus_set()

p = Entry(roots, show="*")
p.grid(row=1, column=1)
p.focus_set()

textEmail = StringVar()
textPassword = StringVar()

def database():
        Label(roots, text=f" {e.get()}").grid(row=10, column=10)
        Label(roots, text=f" {p.get()}").grid(row=20, column=20)

def callback():
    textEmail.set(e.get()) + "\n"
    textPassword.set(p.get()) + "\n"

def EmailPassword():
    Label(roots, text="Email: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    Label(roots, text="Password: ").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Label(roots, textvariable=textEmail).grid(row=10, column=10)
    Label(roots, textvariable=textPassword).grid(row=20, column=20)

    btn_email = Button(roots, text="Save", command= callback).grid(row=2, column=1, stick=E)

    roots.mainloop()

EmailPassword()
```

Everytime i run this code, appear this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: check parenthesis: `textEmail.set(e.get()) + "\n"` you are adding the newline to the call to `set`, it needs to be inside a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in your "callback" function - your .set() function returns None, so you cannot concatenate it to a string. If you want to instead append a newline to the end of your email, you should do:

```py
def callback():
    textEmail.set(e.get() + "\n")
    textPassword.set(p.get() + "\n")
```

This also fixed the error where your code wouldn't delete what was written before.

To add the old passwords/usernames under the new ones, you can do:

```py
def callback():
    textEmail.set(textEmail.get() + e.get() + "\n")
    textPassword.set(textPassword.get() + p.get() + "\n")
```

Comment: This fixed the error, but when I write something, he puts it on the screen, ok, but when I write something else and ask to put it on the screen, he deletes the old one and puts the new one, how do I put the new one under the old one?

Comment: I just made an edit to my old answer that includes this solution.

Comment: If you don't mind would you be able to mark as solved? :)